# Laravel - Paypal Express Checkout Integration

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I'm using [xroot/laravel-paypalpayment](https://github.com/xroot/laravel-paypalpayment)
 library to integrate Paypal Express Checkout.

I installed this package via composer and followed the instructions.
But when I try to create a simple order, I get the following error:

```
Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment.
```

Note that I tried another library and I got the exact same error.

My code:
http://pastebin.com/e7a3dLPt

Comment: Hey, have you figured this out?

Comment: @Ash Yes. the transaction price wasn't equal to the amount of the items.